# PHP call_user_func_array doesn't catch database error

Tags: php, database, error-handling, firebird

I am currently building a database handler. Running on PHP 5.4.16 on top of a Firebird database.

When I have made a prepared statement, I need to execute the SQL with the arguments. I made this function:

```
private function assignParameters($args)
{
    return call_user_func_array('ibase_execute',$args);
}
```

The problem is when I make an error in the args (not giving it the values that are expected), I expect the return to give false(error). `ibase_execute` normally returns false when an error has occurred.

But right now my PHP installation(XAMPP) simply crashes and restarts. I have tried using a try/catch without any luck. The `call_user_func_array` doesn't fail but I would expect it to return the result from the `ibase_execute`. I'm confused.

I should mention that there are no entries in PHP/Apache error logs. The only entry is that the Apache2 server have restarted.

The interbase configuration from phpinfo();

```
Firebird/InterBase Support  dynamic
Compile-time Client Library Version Firebird API version 25
Run-time Client Library Version WI-V6.3.2.26539 Firebird 2.5
```

Any ideas - is this the driver crashing?

**EDIT:**

As requested from Mariuz here is what I got from the debug at crash time. The crash creates two dump report from the http process witch is running the PHP code.

They both contain a lot of information. To much to dump here but here's the excetions.

*Dump 1*

```
Exception Information
In httpd__PID__10168__Date__02_21_2014__Time_03_40_11PM__949__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000008.dmp the assembly instruction at 0x76ed12c7 which does not correspond to any known native module in the process has caused an unknown exception (0xc0000008) on thread 0
```

*Dump 2*

```
Exception Information
MSVCR80!UNWINDUPVEC+50In httpd__PID__10064__Date__02_21_2014__Time_03_40_05PM__321__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp the assembly instruction at msvcr80!UnwindUpVec+50 in C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a\msvcr80.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x00000000 on thread 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a segfault in php please provide the script and a backtrace to it

https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace-win32.php

Comment: I am running XAMPP so the php process is not running for itself. I can get a crash report from Apache2 if that would help.